# HandlebarsJS: Hyperlink containing placeholder?

Tags: html, json, handlebars.js, sendgrid

I have the following table with the hyperlink currently not working:

```
<div class="table">
    <table id="personTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            {{#each person}}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="https://www.mywebsite/person/{{id}}">{{id}}</a></td>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I add the placeholder to the end of the Hyperlink so it is added dynamically?

Comment: Can you further explain what you want to achieve? Is your anchor tag `<a>` not being generated correctly?

Comment: Is the link itself not working, or is the anchor text not being generated (i.e the `{{id}}`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solutions:

> Try single quote '

```
<a href='https://www.mywebsite/person/{{id}}'>{{id}}</a>
```